# ios remote keyboard window

Tags: ios, ios9

In iOS 9, I see a new window appearing in my app that I didn't see before. An image is below. From walking the view tree, I suspect it may be coming from the UIRemoteKeyboardWindow -- but I don't know that.  What is it, and what do I have to do to keep it from appearing?

EDIT: As a commenter pointed out, this is tied to the inputView, i.e. the keyboard. I don't want a keyboard and so disabled it by calling

```
    self.inputView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
```

That did kill the keyboard, but there is still the accessory. I've tried similar tricks to kill the accessory; none of them have worked, yet. Calling self.inputAccessoryView is returning nil, which doesn't help.

[image: new bar]

Comment: This is the input accessory view that is associated with the current keyboard. Normally it will appear on top of the keyboard but if you have a hardware keyboard attached, you only get the accessory view

Comment: Weird, it is appearing when I have no keyboard attached and don't want one as my app has its own.

Answer (score 0):

This got rid of it:

```
-(void) killAccessory {
    UIView* input = self.inputView;
    UIView* parent = input.superview;
    parent.hidden = YES;
}

-(BOOL) becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL r = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    [self killAccessory];
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = [[NSArray alloc] init];
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

the textField use above is the textField which you tap to edit.

Comment: This worked for me, however note that if the textField becomes first responder *before* this code is run, it will have no effect.