# How do I remove Gray Bar at bottom of iPad Screen

Tags: ios, ipad, screen

I recently upgraded my app to iOS10 and now I have this bar at the bottom of an iPad screen:

[image: Bottom of the screen]

I have tried various suggestions to remove it without success. It seems to be related to a textField because it will momentarily disappear after keyboard dismissal.

My question is: What is this view and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Please embed the image instead of linking to it.

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932470/ios-remote-keyboard-window
This did not show up in the search.